# Which Entity Framework Initializer should i use to permanently store my data?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm writing a little project and I had encountered a little problem  that I can't deal with. With the first launch of my application I wish to fill it with some example data. I do this using this class:

```
public class ExampleDataFiller
{
    public BloodBankContext bloodBankContext;
    public List<BloodDonor> ExampleDonators;
    public ExampleDataFiller (BloodBankContext bloodBankContext)
    {
        this.bloodBankContext = bloodBankContext;
        ExampleDonators=new List<BloodDonor>();


        BloodDonor bloodDonor1 = new BloodDonor()
        {
            FirstName="Marcus",
            LastName="Wilkins",
            DateofBirth=new DateTime(1960, 10, 27),
            DateOfRegistration=DateTime.Now,
            BloodType=BloodTypes.ABRHminus,


        };
        ExampleDonators.Add(bloodDonor1);

        BloodDonor bloodDonor2 = new BloodDonor()
        {
            FirstName = "Raul",
            LastName = "Davies",
            DateofBirth = new DateTime(1958, 08, 26),
            DateOfRegistration = DateTime.Now,
            BloodType = BloodTypes.ARHminus,


        };
        ExampleDonators.Add(bloodDonor2);

        BloodDonor bloodDonor3 = new BloodDonor()
        {
            FirstName = "Richard",
            LastName = "Lance",
            DateofBirth = new DateTime(1981, 07, 02),
            DateOfRegistration = DateTime.Now,
            BloodType = BloodTypes.ORHplus,


        };
        ExampleDonators.Add(bloodDonor3);

        BloodDonor bloodDonor4 = new BloodDonor()
        {
            FirstName = "Leonard",
            LastName = "Spencer",
            DateofBirth = new DateTime(1955, 06, 03),
            DateOfRegistration = DateTime.Now,
            BloodType = BloodTypes.ARHplus,


        };
        ExampleDonators.Add(bloodDonor4);

        BloodDonor bloodDonor5 = new BloodDonor()
        {
            FirstName = "Jennifer",
            LastName = "Hays",
            DateofBirth = new DateTime(1960, 01, 13),
            DateOfRegistration = DateTime.Now,
            BloodType = BloodTypes.ARHplus,


        };
        ExampleDonators.Add(bloodDonor5);

        foreach (var donor in ExampleDonators)
        {
            bloodBankContext.BloodDonors.Add(donor);
            bloodBankContext.SaveChanges();
        }

    }


}
```

My application lets user add/remove/edit data in the database. All this seems to work fine as long as the application is running. **The moment I close it and then start again all changes are gone**. Here's my DBContext class:

```
public class BloodBankContext: DbContext
{
    public BloodBankContext() : base("BloodBankDatabase1") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<BloodBankContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BloodBankContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<BloodDonor> BloodDonors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BloodDonation> BloodDonations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StoredBlood> storedBlood { get; set; }    
}
```

I know it's due to the fact of the initializer I'm using: *DropCreateDatabaseAlways* but I've been playing around with other 2 initializers and even wrote my own one but nothing seems to work for me. Only thing I managed to achieve was doubling my records in the database. Here's how I start my application:

```
public partial class BloodBankManager : Form
{
    public static BloodBankContext context;
public BloodBankManager()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        context = new BloodBankContext();
        ExampleDataFiller exampleDataFiller = new ExampleDataFiller(context);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = context.BloodDonors.Local.ToBindingList();

        comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BloodTypes));

    }
}
```

So my question is: **what's the proper way for storing data between applicaton launches?**

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want to initialize the database always by this data ? so when you restart the app again, this data always available to the user ?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to see the initial data+any changes done by previous users.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set any initializer, but your class has to set this data once, and check if the database already has data in the data before add them again.

So, if you want to keep the data exactly as it is, you need to set the initializer by null

So, Something like this :

```
public class BloodBankContext : DbContext
        {
            public BloodBankContext()
                : base("BloodBankDatabase1")
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<BloodBankContext>(null); // this means that keep the database data as it is and don't change it.
            }
            public DbSet<BloodDonor> BloodDonors { get; set; }
            public DbSet<BloodDonation> BloodDonations { get; set; }
            public DbSet<StoredBlood> storedBlood { get; set; }
        }
```

and you can do something like this to check if the data already initialized

```
     public ExampleDataFiller (BloodBankContext bloodBankContext)
        {
            this.bloodBankContext = bloodBankContext;

            // Only initialize the data if none is there
            if(!bloodBankContext.BloodDonors.Any())
            {
                 ExampleDonators=new List<BloodDonor>();

                 var bloodDonor1 = new BloodDonor()
                 {
                     FirstName="Marcus",
                     LastName="Wilkins",
                     DateofBirth=new DateTime(1960, 10, 27),
                     DateOfRegistration=DateTime.Now,
                     BloodType=BloodTypes.ABRHminus,
                 };

                 //.
                 //.
                 //.
                 // etc
            }
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Unfortunately it wasn't what I was looking for. Apparently I missed this method: context.BloodDonors.Load();